# Limit Number of Items in ObservableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to create an extender to limit the number of items that can be pushed into an observable array. The problem I am running into is when the write is supposed to happen. I get an error regarding the object doesn't have a method 'push'.

Here is the fiddle to demonstrate what I'm talking about. When you click any of the check boxes, the error will show up. You have to have your developer tools window open in Chrome or Firefox to see the error.

http://jsfiddle.net/pEzsb/55/

Comment: Knockout is expecting an observableArray, but you've replaced it with a computed observable that doesn't have a push() method. You will need to find a different solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

http://jsfiddle.net/zero21xxx/B3RgK/

Basically just control whether the check box is enabled or not.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick and dirty way to do this.

```
ko.extenders.arrayMaxLength = function(target, length) {
    target.push2 = target.push;
    target.push = function (value) {
        if (this().length < length) {
            this.push2(value);
        }
    };
    return target;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/2bTra/1/

It's not very useful since it doesn't stop the checkboxes being checked which I assume is what you want to happen, it simply stops the value making it to the array.

A better solution would be to write a custom checked binding handler with a limit value that would stop them getting checked.

Hope this helps.